# c++11 ambiguous << overload

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a namespace containing a class that is supposed to mimic the functionalty of a stack, inside I have a print funciton and a out stream overload that calls the print function to print out the contents of a template of the vector in my stack.h file I define those funtions as

```
namespace foo
{
   template <typename T>
   class Stack{
      public:
         //...
         void print(std::ostream& os,char ofs = ' ');
         //...
      private:
         std::vector<T> stack;
   };

   template <typename T>
   std::ostream&  operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Stack<T>& A);
}
```

and in my stack.hpp file

```
template<typename T>
void foo::Stack<T>::print(std::ostream& os, char ofc)
{
   for(auto itr = stack.begin(); itr != stack.end(); ++itr)
   {
      os << *itr << ofc;
   }
}

template<typename T>
std::ostream& foo::operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Stack<T>& A)
{
   A.print(os);
   return os;
}
```

then in my stack.cpp driver I make a stack object "b" and fill it with integers and call the .stack::print function and it prints out the elements with the ofc fill charater inbetween but when I call cout << b; the compiler complains that the operator<< overload is abiguous saying," operand types are 'std::ostream { aka std::basic_ostream}' and ' this::Stack')"
I am confused because my print function works flawlessly and my overload just calls that function shouldn't work just the same?

Comment: I'm sorry I dont really use this as the name for the namespace It was just the first thing that came to mind i changed it to foo instead

Comment: You call a non-const method `print` for a const object `A`.

Comment: Ah! so I should just ad void foo::Stack<T>::print(...) const;?

Comment: Yes, I'm surprised the compiler didn't complain about it. With gcc, there's no such error as "overload is ambiguous".

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with

```
namespace foo
{
   template<typename T>
   void Stack<T>::print(std::ostream& os, char ofc)
   {
        for(auto itr = stack.begin(); itr != stack.end(); ++itr)
        {
               os << *itr << ofc;
        }
   }
   template<typename T>
   std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Stack<T>& A)
   {
            A.print(os);
            return os;
   }
}
```

?

I mean... you've defined `operator<<(std::ostream &, const Stack<T> &)` inside namespace `foo` but when you use it

```
template<typename T>
 void foo::Stack<T>::print(std::ostream& os, char ofc)
 {
        for(auto itr = stack.begin(); itr != stack.end(); ++itr)
        {
               os << *itr << ofc;
        }
 }
```

you're in a method defined in a namespace `foo` but you're not in namespace `foo`.

Comment: That's because I'm implementing it in my stack.hpp file where im not in the namespace, so dont I have to specify the namespace with the scope  operator so the complier know that I'm refering to it?

Comment: @NeoZeus - not sure but I suppose so; have you tried?

Comment: I’m not sure what the difference is between your code and mine other than void print is no longer in the stack class